# How do I create a rectangle with an open corner in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I'm brand new at creating icons.

I have an issue regarding changing the shape of a rectangle. The bottom one is what I have. But I'd like to change the rectangle to look something like the top rectangle.  [image]

I have of course tried to get it to work  by using the Pathfinder palette. But it gives a different result than I expected. 
[image]

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the point you want to delete with Direct Selection Tool ( shortcut A) and then press delete button of your keyboard. [image: Tutorial]

Comment: Did you do this after using pathfinder? It works.
We need more 2 points in the shape before we use the direct selection tool (A). This can be done with Pen Tool (P) > Add anchor point tool.

Comment: @RaquelFantasia This *should* work just fine. I'm betting the rectangle has the stroke defined in the Appearance Panel or there's some other technical issue you aren't aware of and aren't sharing.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. *Exits stage left*

Comment: What ignorance @Vincent?? Your method also works. (although you may not need the scissors, etc. [see here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jlVIy.gif))

Comment: @Scott I'm aware the blue rectangle around the shape will disappear when We use the Anchor Point Tool. I just used the image of mortenstarck to show what anchor should be deleted.

Comment: @Vincent I forgive you. I will try to use images in the next time to avoid misunderstandings. :)

Comment: Sorry Raquel.. I meant to ping @mortenstock rather than you. My comment wasn't meant to be directed at you.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with your top rectangle:

1. Select the `Add Anchor Point` tool. It's part of the pen tool, so click and hold the pen tol button in the toolbox to have it show: it's a pen with a plus sign. The shortcut key is <kbd>=</kbd>.
2. Click on the rectangle path to add anchors to it. Add anchors at the points where you want the gap to be: one at the start of the gap, one at the end.
3. Select the `Scissors` tool. It's part of the `Eraser` tool, and looks like, well, a pair of scissors. Shortcut is <kbd>C</kbd>.
4. Click the lower right anchor of your rectangle. This will cause the closed path to open, and the single anchor is now split into two, overlapping anchors.
5. Select the `Delete Anchor Point` tool. It's part of the pen tool and it's a pen with a minus sign. The shortcut key is <kbd>–</kbd> (minus).
6. Click both (overlapping) lower right anchors to delete them both.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are getting an unexpected result is because you are working with a path, not a fill object. Pathfinder works differently with the two of them. (See Comparison below)

If it doesn't matter to you whether the object is a fill or a path, then I suggest trying this:
Go to the top menu with your path selected, click Object > Expand;
Now, try to use your Minus Front Pathfinder. It should be what you were expecting.

Step 1 - Expand:

With your path selected;

[image: Step1]

Click on Object > Expand.
[image: Step2]

This dialog box will pop up, just hit OK.
[image: Step3]

Step 2 - Cheating a little bit:
Draw another Rectangle **above** the first:
[image: Step4]

Step 3 - Pathfinder:

Use the "Minus Front" function:

[image: Step5]

And you're done!

The reason this happens is that illustrator handles paths and fills as different entities. Basically, instead of making a fill object (What you were expecting to happen), it created another path that contoured to the pathfinder result.

By "expanding" the path, you get a fill object that you can manipulate easier with Pathfinder. Note how the first image has a single path in the center, while after being expanded, it becomes a fill.